# Best way to handle data for several options C#

Tags: c#

My program workflow:

1) Show menu

2) Catch option by switch

2.1)Add float to a list

2.2)Increment int1

2.3)Increment int2

2.4)Show inputs

Now I wanna to add a generator which will print in console how my fiber track looks like. For ex:

1) Added a section of 20km lenght

2) Added a weld in latest secion

3) Added a regenerator

4) Added connector

5) Added section of 10km lenght

And I want to get in my console:

> This is how your track looks like:
>   [Transmitter]-> [--20km track--] -> [Weld] -> [Regenerator] -> [Connector] > -> [--10km track--]

First question is what kind of List should I create to handle my track design? I tought only to make a integer list, and make a encoding method to convert for example 1 to section 2 for weld 3 for connector etc.

Any suggestions would be nice! Thank you for your time and patience.

```
public class Program
{

    public int WeldCount;
    public int ConnectroCount;
    public List<float> section = new List<float>();
    //public List<> TrackElements = new List<>();

    public Program()
    {
        section.Add(0);

    }
    public void showResults()
    {
        float allSections = 0;
        foreach (float item in section)
        {
            allSections += item;
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Weld count: {0}, connector count: {1}, sum of sections: {2}", WeldCount,ConnectroCount,allSections);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }



    public void finalConstruction()
    {




    }


    public static void mainMenu()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Add: \n1. Section \n2. Weld \n3. Regenerator\n4. Show results");




    }


    public void menuChoose()
    {

        var key = Console.ReadKey();

        switch (key.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.D1:
            case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Give lenght:");
                float result;
                float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result);


                section.Add(result);



                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();

                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D2:

                WeldCount++;
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D3:
                ConnectroCount++;
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;

            case ConsoleKey.D4:
                showResults();
                mainMenu();
                menuChoose();
                break;





            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Coś ty odjebał");
                break;
        }

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Program program = new Program();
        mainMenu();
        program.menuChoose();




    }





}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You don't know how to organize job steps (well, define `class Step`), how to link them (should they come in order?), which data type use to define it (how about `List<Step>`?) or what?

Comment: "Now I wanna to add a generator which will print in console how my fiber track looks like. For ex" Huh? Generator? Fiber track? We're not building the same stuff you are OP, give us some context!

Comment: @Sinatr: is a List<step> some kind of data type?

Comment: @Glubus: Okay so... think like this program is TRACK DESIGNER. If you desing your track you can add elements from switch menu welds, connectors etc. And when user finish I  want to give an option which will print designed track.

Comment: @J.DoeMilion The comment was suggesting that you create a class to model the data.  There's nothing built-in for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `List<string>`. This way you can add the Transmitter, Welder and Your Track and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with using classes, I'd start by making a Track class.
The problem with having a list of floats is, you cannot be sure of the order they were input, so how can you map a specific length to a specific track?

This is how simple your Track class can be:

```
public class Track
{
    public string Name;
    public float Length;
}
```

In your mainMenu, you can add new tracks by saying:

```
Track t = new Track();
t.Name = "Welding";
t.Length = 4.5f;
trackElements.Add(t);
```

And simply display it like this:

```
public void showResults()
{
    foreach(Track item in trackElements)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ": " + item.Length);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Number of sections: " + trackElements.Count());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Interesting way of creating this program, I will consider this